# How to reduce 'Cached' memory in embedded linux with ramdisk

Tags: linux, caching, memory, embedded

I run a small linux embedded system (2.6.29.6).  Kernel loads from Flash into ramdisk
  (tmpfs).  I need to find more ram.

From /proc/meminfo I see I have a 'Cached:' using a lot of memory.   My understanding
  is this is the disk cache.  However, I don't have a traditional hard disk.  I have
  a ram disk.  So I think, for my situation, this cache is just eating up my valuable
  memory.

Is there a way to reduce the size of this cache?

thanks in advance!

LB

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that the cache memory won't be released to your application the moment its needed?

Comment: I think this question should be rather posted to ServerFault than here.

Answer (score 1):

Linux shows the memory used by the tmpfs contents as 'cached'. So it will a lot of memory if you have a lot of tmpfs data.

Also if you have loaded anything (maybe the data stored to tmpfs later) from any other medium it could got into the 'cached' pool too. But that is no need to worry – that memory will be freed when needed for anything else.